# How to refresh firebase remote config cache immediately base on cacheExpirationSeconds?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

I have problem to refresh remote config value in each seconds even i have set `isDeveloperModeEnabled` to be true. Here is the code to refresh cache in each second, i want to refresh it immediately because for testing purpose:

```
firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(1) 
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "remote config is fetched.")
                    firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched()
                }
            }
```

and here i set developer mode becaome true:

```
val remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
val configSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .build()
    remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings)
```

the problem is still i cannot refresh remote config value in each second even though i have set developer mode become true ? should i wait 12 hour to test it ?

Comment: You do know remote config does not automatically refresh right? It will only refresh when you call `fetch` and the cache expiration has been hit so if you need to do it every second then you need some sort of polling interval to continually call that

Answer (score 0):

check this out, see cache expires after 1hour, modify as your need

```
 private void fetch() {

    //loaded defaults..
    String result = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(VERSION_CODE);
    Log.d(TAG, " remote  default value  before fetching : VERSION_CODE  : " + result);
    long cacheExpiration = 3600;
    if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
        cacheExpiration = 0;
    }

    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Fetch Succeeded");
                        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Fetch Failed");
                    }
                    handlerResultRemoteConfig();
                }
            });
}
```